# an expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected,

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm fairly new to SQL and have been stuck trying to run the following code.

```
SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE LEN([User]​.[Telephone]) == 10
```

Errors -

- an expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected,
- Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
  Incorrect syntax near '='.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE LEN([User]​.[Telephone]) = 10

Comment: In MySQL to check equality you use `=` (not `==` as we have in many programming languages) And for assignment in MySQL use `:=`  (not `=`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `=` insetad of `==`

```
SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE LEN([User]​.[Telephone]) = 10
```

becouse `=` is correct sql equal operator.